# Most efficient interface for enduser: Winforms/WCF versus Web Browser access

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, wcf, webforms

What I need to do is meet my competition and 'update' my winforms application so that it is fully accessible via an online service.

I'm not sure whether to recode my winforms app so that it uses WCF/Odata to access the database or whether the whole app will need re-writing as a webforms app and moving the database to the hosted website. The later option will likely be the more difficult of the two options given my coding experience. At present, the database resides on the end-users PC and the winforms app provides 100% of the end-users access. There is also a web interface that provides the end-user's clients access to reservations, their own user details etc. The web interface is self-hosted on the end-users PC.

With regards to serving up the data to the end-user, will there be an appreciable time difference between my proposed winforms app retrieving and consuming the data from a remote hosted database VERSUS a fully hosted webforms/database app? Can this difference be quantified before I take the plunge?

Comment: this answer is likely to be closed because it will draw too many opinions.  My opinion is that if speed is an issue you should build some small tests to see exactly what the difference will be given your architecture.  Otherwise this is all quite a broad topic for this format.

Comment: @papogomez I think this will be the only solution to my quandary however I thought it was a simple question that would entice x votes for webforms and y votes for winforms but alas I guess you are right.

Answer (score 1):

Web versus Desktop is a huge topic.

My two cents:

**Web:**

1 - Pros:

- Accesible from all kinds of devices (PC, Mac, Smartphone, Tablet).
- No installation required.
- Only server deployment / update is required.

2 - Cons:

- Stateless (this means no client side cache, for example)
- Less control over the client computer's features (File System and the like).
- Browser hell (UI looks/behaves different on every browser)
- harder to code due to crappy javascript everywhere
- Web-based vulnerabilities (such as XSS and the like)

**.Net Windows Desktop:**

1 - Pros:

- Stateful (you can cache lots of data in the client).
- More control over the client computer's features.
- Looks the same on every machine.
- easier to code due to stateful nature and no javascript (hooray).

2 - Cons:

- Only works in Windows. No smartphone, no Mac, no tablet.
- client installation required (which might include a .Net Framework installation).
- Server + client updates required (easier with ClickOnce).

That said, winforms is a really old technology no one cares about anymore, and which does not support anything. Web applications can be made to look and feel beautifully with some CSS. winforms looks ugly no matter how hard you try to improve it.

If you go the `Windows Desktop` route, you'd rather upgrade your application to WPF.

Comment: Thank you for your comments which I appreciate and understand however you haven't answered or offered an opinion on the only fact that I needed to know. That is (in brief) - which is faster in terms of time taken to say refresh a screen full of data obtained from the database?

Comment: @David that answer is so subjective that it cannot possibly be answered given such generalities.  HighCore, love your work +1

Comment: @David none is "faster" per se. You have to make it faster, for example in Web you would use AJAX and stuff like that to refresh the screen without forcing a postback and the like. and in Desktop + WCF you may use GZIP compression to shrink the transmitted data, and local cache in the client to prevent having to go to the server all the time.

Comment: well I believe that it is easier in web. You can have admin pages with few commands.In wpf free datagrids suck.In web you can do much more.